# I can't upgrade ti.map

Tags: dictionary, module, appcelerator

I'm not able to upgrade ti.map, because in the dist folder i have 2 jar files, but when I select one of these for install the module, it says it's overwriting files but nothing change.

I usually have no problem in install modules from jar or zip files

Comment: Could you provide some more context, code, versions etc?

Comment: Do you really need to install this map module from .zip or jar files?
I think you should simply add it from tiapp.xml Overview mode.